# Is there a difference between Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] and Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET, is there a difference between these?

1. `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`
2. `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]`

Request.Headers is clearer to me, but I commonly see sample code using `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` (along with `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`) and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no difference between `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` and `Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]`.

The documentation for the [IIS Server Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) starting with "HTTP_" says: "The value stored in the header ."

So `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` just returns the `X_Forwarded_For` header. Nothing else.

The difference between `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` is only apparent when there is a proxy server between you and the client. In those cases, `REMOTE_ADDR` will have the address of the proxy server, and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will have the address of the end client.

If there is no proxy, then `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` will be empty and `REMOTE_ADDR` will have the address of the end client.

Comment: and the actual domain used when using a Reversed Proxy on the IIS, how to get URL Rewrite to add that if you have multiple domains ?